# Thymeleaf not seeing objcet added to model with model.addObject()

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm haveing problems with thymeleaf in Java project because it doesn't see any objects I'm adding to my models.

Here's my GET mapping:

```
@GetMapping(USER_PATH)
public ModelAndView getUserOffersView(){
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("/panel/user/offer-list");
    List<Firearm> firearmList = firearmService.findAllByUserId(userService.findLogged().get().getUserId());
    model.addObject("firearmList", firearmList);
    return model;
}
```

And that's HTML where I'M tryign to access it:

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4" th:each="offer : ${firearmList}">
                    <div class="card mb-4 product-wap rounded-0" style="max-width: 250px; max-height: 500px">
                        <div class="card rounded-0">
                            <img class="card-img rounded-0 img-fluid" src="/img/shop_01.jpg">
                            <div class="card-img-overlay rounded-0 product-overlay d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                    <li><a class="btn btn-success text-white" href="shop-single.html"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></a></li>
                                    <li><a class="btn btn-success text-white mt-2" href="shop-single.html"><i class="far fa-eye"></i></a></li>
                                    <li><a class="btn btn-success text-white mt-2" href="shop-single.html"><i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <a href="shop-single.html" class="h3 text-decoration-none" th:text="${offer.title}"></a>
                            <ul class="w-100 list-unstyled d-flex justify-content-between mb-0">
                                <li></li>
                            </ul>
                            <p class="text-center mb-0" th:text="${offer.price}"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

For some reason thymeleaf doesn't recongize any object, but sometimes if I type the object's value I'm trying to access, eg *offer.price* as shown here it DOES SHOW in the browser, so it can access the data, but it does not see the object, which makes coding incredibly painful. I'm not sure if that's related, but my controllers cannot find any views in the project: [PIC REL HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTMYD.png).

My pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>



<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
        <version>2.16.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.21</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently for some reason template resolvers did not autoconfigure, so I needed to add this code in my configuration, and it works:

```
 @Bean
public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver(){
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
    templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine springTemplateEngine(){
    SpringTemplateEngine springTemplateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    springTemplateEngine.addTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    return springTemplateEngine;
}

@Bean
public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver(){
    ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(springTemplateEngine());
    viewResolver.setOrder(1);
    return viewResolver;
}
```